# HMAccessoryBrowser and unconfigured WAC-enabled Wi-Fi accessories

Tags: ios, external-accessory, homekit, wac

It seems to me that `HMAccessoryBrowser` can see not only unconfigured HomeKit accessories that are already on the same Wi-Fi network as the phone, but also WAC-enabled accessories running in setup mode, waiting to be configured (i.e. not on Wi-Fi network).

In the past I needed `EAWiFiUnconfiguredAccessoryBrowser` to complement `HMAccessoryBrowser` to see all devices (like it's done in the sample [HMCatalog app](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/HomeKitCatalog/Introduction/Intro.html)), but now it seems like "external" accessories appear in HMAccessoryBrowser scan results alongside "normal" HomeKit accessories.

If tapped, I can see this dialogue:

> **Add Accessory to Network?**
>
> You'll need to allow this accessory to access your Wi-Fi network before you add it to Home.
>
> `[Don't Allow]` - `[Allow]`

If I tap "Allow", the devices joins my current Wi-Fi network automatically. Which is great news, because the user doesn't need to see the ugly bland WAC dialogue created by `EAWiFiUnconfiguredAccessoryBrowser.configureAccessory()` call that does not fit with the rest of app look and feel.

However...

I have never seen this before, and it seems to be *wildly undocumented.* There are zero mentions of it in `ExternalAccessory` or `HomeKit` framework documentation, as well as no trace whatsoever of the dialogue wording anywhere.

Is it officially an officially endorsed way to configure WAC-enabled HomeKit accessories? When did it become supported? iOS 9? 10?